# Why use skids for landing gear on an orbiter?

Tags: spacecraft, landing, landing-gear

Why does the Dream Chaser use a skid as the nose landing gear?

[image]

Wouldn't this increase the risk of accidents or damage to the runway when landing on a paved runway?

Comment: Can’t say for sure but removing the tire remove mass, complexity, moving parts, ... all the kind of things space engineers hate.

Comment: The load on nose landing gear seems to be much lower than on the other landing gear.

Comment: I agree with @Antzi, pressurized tires which spin and wear and have bearings and rubber are probably way more complex than a simple skid plate which can easily be exchanged. Also, if you watch the video, it balances on its rear wheels for a long time so it's probably very tail heavy.

Comment: Related; question (also a good answer); [Runway landing with a front skid instead of wheel - how does steering happen? (Dreamchaser)](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/45692/14213)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sierra Nevada Corporation's answer to NASASpaceFlight on this topic in 2012 was the following:

> Speaking of the rationale for opting to use a skid strip, SNC noted it is a simple, light, safe option. They also added that there had been some issues with the analysis of the performance of tires in the space environment and this eliminates one of the tires – with the other two tires easier to control than the nose wheel if there’s a problem with one of them.

- [*SNC outline Dream Chaser’s Enterprise-style landing test approach*](https://www.nasaspaceflight.com/2012/06/snc-dream-chasers-enterprise-test-approach/)

As Antzi mentioned in the comments, the overall cost-benefit analysis seems to favour a skid over an additional wheel. I'd love to hear more from the SNC engineers on this, but they seem to be tightlipped on the design choice.